# What does "is unique" Eclipse UML stand for?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, uml, unique

I'm actually designing UML on eclipse and I just face a "is Unique" checkbox on a variable model properties. Why does that mean? Each variable in a same class isn't supposed to be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll simply refer to the UML specs on p. 34 here:

> If the MultiplicityElement is specified as unique (i.e., isUnique is true), then the collection of values in an instantiation of this Element must be unique. That is, no two values in the collection may be equal, where equality of objects (instances of Classes) is based on object identity while equality of data values (instances of DataTypes) and Signal instances is based on value (see also sub clauses 10.2, 10.3, and 11.4 on DataTypes, Signals and Classes, respectively ). If a MultiplicityElement is not multivalued, then the value for isUnique has no semantic effect.
>
> Taken together, the isOrdered and isUnique properties can be used to specify that the collection of values in an instantiation of a MultiplicityElement is of one of four types. Table 7.1shows the traditional names given to each of these collection types.

[image]

Comment: That make sense for array or collection. But why this checkbox is here for "1-D" data?

Comment: I'd guess it's an implementation flaw to not suppress it there. Technically a 1-D array is a single element and vice versa.

Comment: @M.Ferru notice this line in the answer "If a MultiplicityElement is not multivalued, then the value for isUnique has no semantic effect." (dtto for isOrdered), but the model will still remember what you choose (it's an independent attribute)